# Two phase XSLT transformation converting string to XML first

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string>
&lt;Table&gt;
&lt;Rows&gt;
&lt;Row Id="0"&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_NAME" XPath="Ins.Name"&gt;Jane&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_LASTNAME" XPath="Ins.LastName"&gt;Smith&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;/Row&gt;
&lt;Row Id="1"&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_NAME" XPath="Ins.Name"&gt;Joe&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_LASTNAME" XPath="Ins.LastName"&gt;Miller&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;/Row&gt;
&lt;Row Id="2"&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_NAME" XPath="Ins.Name"&gt;George&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;Column Name="INS_LASTNAME" XPath="Ins.LastName"&gt;Ramsey&lt;/Column&gt;
&lt;/Row&gt;
&lt;/Rows&gt;
&lt;/Table&gt;
</string>
```

and I would like to transform it to this XML using a **single** XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer><Name>Jane</Name><LastName>Smith</LastName></Customer>
  <Customer><Name>Joe</Name><LastName>Miller</LastName></Customer>
  <Customer><Name>George</Name><LastName>Ramsey</LastName></Customer>
</Customers>
```

I can do it with two different XSLT's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Customers>
      <xsl:for-each select="Table/Rows/Row">
      <Customer>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="Column[@Name='INS_NAME']" /></Name>
        <LastName><xsl:value-of select="Column[@Name='INS_LASTNAME']" /></LastName>
      </Customer>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Customers>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have been reading about multi phase transformations but I can't seem to get it. I have tried saving the first XSLT in a variable but it seems `disable-output-escaping="yes"` does not work when saving to a variable.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

**New information (Edit)**

I am now translating the string this way:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="stringXml">
      &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(/,'&gt;','&gt;'),'&lt;','&lt;')" />
    </xsl:variable>
...
```

How can I do a transformation on the resulting XML stored in stringXML?

**Final Solution (Edit)**

```
<msxml:script implements-prefix="myLib" language="C#">
<msxml:assembly name="System.Web"/>
<msxml:using namespace="System.Web"/>
<![CDATA[
public System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator convertText(string text)
{
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
      doc.LoadXml(text);
      return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("/");
}
]]>
</msxml:script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems disable-output-escaping="yes" does not work when saving to a
>   variable.

Your observation is correct.

**DOE only affects the serialization of the (final) result of the transformation and isn't applied on intermediary trees**.

Here is what the **[W3C XSLT 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#disable-output-escaping)** explicitly says:

> "*An XSLT processor will only be able to disable output escaping if it
>   controls how the result tree is output. This may not always be the
>   case. For example, the result tree may be used as the source tree for
>   another XSLT transformation instead of being output."*

The same negative answer holds for trying to use a variable, whose value is a string, containing a textual representation of an XML document.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Can you think of another way to convert the string to an XML?

Comment: Not in pure XSLT (1.0 or 2.0). This can be done using a tiny extension function. I can give you one in C#, if you'd need this.

Comment: I have not studied extension functions so I don't know if I could use one. I am now creating a text output with the XSLT but I need to transform the resulting XML stored in a variable. Is this possible? (see edit on original post)

Comment: @supercoco, No, the variable still contains just text -- not an XML document. As I said before, you need an extension function, or you need to wait until XSLT 3.0 where there might be a standard `parse-xml()` function.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Finally I was able to create the extension function (wasn't that hard after all). Unfortunately the environment where I am executing this XSLT does not allow scripts :(. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @supercoco: You are welcome. In case scripts (defining inline extension functions) aren't allowed, then one needs to write this code as part of an extension object.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I needed to parse an escaped XML inside my actual XML.  I will post up my solution to also help someone else.  Please also note that I am also using Saxon-PE parser.

In my situation I have the original XML that contains an escaped XML in a child node.  I needed to get the inner XML inside the **RootNode** of the escaped XML.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyTestXml>
    <SomeXmlStuff>
        <Text1>Hello</Text1>
        <Text2>World</Text2>
    </SomeXmlStuff>
    <SomeEscapedXml>&lt;RootNode&gt;&lt;FirstNode&gt;Hello&lt;/FirstNode&gt;&lt;SecondNode&gt;World&lt;/SecondNode&gt;&lt;ThirdNode&gt;Again&lt;/ThirdNode&gt;&lt;/RootNode&gt;</SomeEscapedXml>
</MyTestXml>
```

When you unescaped the XML, it looks like this:

```
<RootNode>
    <FirstNode>Hello</FirstNode>
    <SecondNode>World</SecondNode>
    <ThirdNode>Again</ThirdNode>
</RootNode>
```

With the following XSLT transformation is applied on the source XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"

                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl saxon">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <MyOutput>      
            <xsl:call-template name="GetRootNodeInnerXml">
                <xsl:with-param name="escapedXml" select="MyTestXml/SomeEscapedXml" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </MyOutput>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetRootNodeInnerXml">
        <xsl:param name="escapedXml" required="yes" />

        <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse($escapedXml)/RootNode/node()"/>

        <!--  You can also use this line below if you're not using saxon parser.  Just make sure your parser supports XSL 3.0  -->
        <!--
        <xsl:copy-of select="fn:parse-xml($escapedXml)/RootNode/node()" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"/>
        -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives you the following output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<MyOutput>
    <FirstNode>Hello</FirstNode>
    <SecondNode>World</SecondNode>
    <ThirdNode>Again</ThirdNode>
</MyOutput>
```